# How to simplify this json array?

Tags: json

Can I simplify the answers array ?

```
{
    "Questions": [{
            "Question": "Which is the largest fresh water lake in Kerala?",
            "CorrectAnswer": 2,
            "Answers": [{
                "Answer": "Vembanad Lake"
            }, {
                "Answer": "Pookode Lake"
            }, {
                "Answer": "Sasthamcotta Lake"
            }, {
                "Answer": "Vellayani Lake"
            }]
        }, {
            "Question": "Chennara, the birth place of Mahakavi Vallathol is in:",
            "CorrectAnswer": 1,
            "Answers": [{
                "Answer": "Thrissur District"
            }, {
                "Answer": "Malappuram District"
            }, {
                "Answer": "Palakkad District"
            }, {
                "Answer": "Alappuzha District"
            }]
        }]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, don't make answers an array of objects with the string `Answer` as the key for each item. Just make it an array of strings:

```
    "Answers": [{
        "Answer": "Vembanad Lake"
    }, {
        "Answer": "Pookode Lake"
    }, {
        "Answer": "Sasthamcotta Lake"
    }, {
        "Answer": "Vellayani Lake"
    }]
```

becomes:

```
    "Answers": [
     "Vembanad Lake"
     "Pookode Lake",
     "Sasthamcotta Lake",
     "Vellayani Lake"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you don't need the answers to be objects, just use an array of strings like so

```
{"Answers":["answer 1, ", "answer 2"]}
```